# How to use WebView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, webview

I have this code, but it raise many errors:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var webView = WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://github.com")!))
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            webView
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

like: Generic struct 'VStack' requires that 'WebView' conform to 'View'

Comment: The `WebView` should be in the `body` not in an `@State`

Comment: If I would process events on WebView, I need a reference to it. I would handle later when `authorize` call finish and Github return `code` .

Comment: SwiftUI Views can’t be held like that, they have to be in a ViewBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works on my machine but you should probably use `WebView` inside your body.

Example:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://github.com")!))
    }
}
```

Comment: Got this: `Return type of property 'body' requires that 'WebView' conform to 'View'`

Comment: Is your `WebView` wrapped in  a `UIViewRepresentable`?